# searching a table in a database with result from another table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

hi i am trying to write a php to grab a specific category of post in a wordpress database, this is what i got so far:

```
$q = "select * from table1 where column like 'condition'";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$id = array();
if($r){
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    $link = $row["object_id"];
    $id[] = array(
        "postid"=>$link,    
        );
    }
}
else{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

now i am trying to use the result i got from pervious code to search another table to get something else. i am new to php so i am hoping to get some help

thanks in advance

Comment: you can nest another query inside of that one, or you can write a function to do the query and call that inside of this one, or you might be able to write a better query with a join on the other table and do this all with 1 query

Comment: @RightClick thanks very much, i figure it out by using join

Comment: excellent....that's the best of the 3 options I listed.  Good job learning something new and figuring it out !